# Send JSON Client Object data to C# Server on a different computer

Tags: javascript, c#, json, client-server, kinect

Currently, I am running this code which sends JSON Client data to C# Server but both Client and Server need to be running on the same computer. I wanted to know if there is a way to send the data from Client to Server on another computer assuming there on the same LAN network? Instead of having to run both the Server and Client code on the same computer I want to run it on a different computer and have the client send over the data over a network to the C# server code. I have main shown below some of the code used in the Client & Server program. I want multiple computers to run the client code and send the JSON data of the Kinect joint over to the C# server.

Client:

```
  // Connect to the WebSocket server!
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001");
    socket.onopen = function (event) 
    {
        label.innerHTML = "Connection open";
    }

    //Display the skeleton joints.
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.skeletons.length; i++) { 
                for (var j = 0; j < jsonObject.skeletons[i].joints.length; j++)
         {
         var joint = jsonObject.skeletons[i].joints[j];
         context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(joint.x * 400 +320, (-joint.y) * 400 +240, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
         console.log(joint.name);                                           
         context.closePath();
         context.fill();    
                }
            }
        }
        else if (event.data instanceof Blob) 
       {
        var blob = event.data;
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var source = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        camera.src = source;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(source);
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
namespace WebSockets.Server
{
    public static class BodySerializer
    {

        [DataContract]
        class JSONSkeletonCollection
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "skeletons")]
            public List<JSONSkeleton> Skeletons { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        class JSONSkeleton
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string ID { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "joints")]
            public List<JSONJoint> Joints { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        class JSONJoint
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "x")]
            public double X { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "y")]
            public double Y { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "z")]
            public double Z { get; set; }
        }

        public static string Serialize(this List<Body> skeletons, CoordinateMapper mapper, Mode mode)
        {
            JSONSkeletonCollection jsonSkeletons = new JSONSkeletonCollection { Skeletons = new List<JSONSkeleton>() };

            foreach (var skeleton in skeletons)
            {
                JSONSkeleton jsonSkeleton = new JSONSkeleton
                {
                    ID = skeleton.TrackingId.ToString(),
                    Joints = new List<JSONJoint>()
                };

                foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints.Values)
                {


                    jsonSkeleton.Joints.Add(new JSONJoint
                    {
                        Name = joint.JointType.ToString(),
                        X = joint.Position.X,
                        Y = joint.Position.Y,
                        Z = joint.Position.Z

                    });
                }

                jsonSkeletons.Skeletons.Add(jsonSkeleton);
            }

            return Serialize(jsonSkeletons);
        }

        private static string Serialize(object obj)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);

                return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output (running both Server and Client code on the same computer):

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vs5R.png)

Comment: Just run Web Server code on a different PC, Ensure the port it's running on is open, and change `localhost` for either the hostname or IP address of the server?

Comment: I tried running it on a different PC but I didn't change the localhost to the IP address of the server so I will try that right now. So would it just be `("http://192.168.X.X")` instead of `("ws://localhost:8001")` in the client code?

Comment: I would expect it'll be `ws://192.168.X.X:8001` if the server is listening on port 8001 - but bear in mind the firewall on the server PC (and any other firewall between the two PCs) will have to be configured to allow traffic on port 8001 through.

Comment: I had two computer one ran the server code in C# and another computer ran the client code. The client code job is to use display the skeleton. And upon changing the IP address as you mentioned it did just that the server code was running the Kinect and displaying the data in C# program and the client code in index.html was displaying the skeleton. But I want the Client code to run the Kinect and display the skeleton and send its data to the C# server. So is there a way to run the Kinect in the client code and pass over its joint data on the C# server?

Comment: I expect so, but at the moment your client is running in a web browser.  If you want the client to be able to interface with other hardware then you'll need to re-write the client in c# too...